# Select records only if specific column has two or more different ip_address within the same day

Tags: mysql, group-by, having-clause

I want to be able to select records that has different `ip_address` within the same day and group it by `name`.

Given the example:

```
name   |    ip_address    |    date
user1  |    127.0.0.1     |  2020-01-01
user1  |    127.0.0.2     |  2020-01-01
user2  |    127.0.0.1     |  2020-01-01
user2  |    127.0.0.2     |  2020-01-02
user3  |    127.0.0.1     |  2020-01-03
user3  |    127.0.0.4     |  2020-01-03
user3  |    127.0.0.1     |  2020-01-04
user3  |    127.0.0.1     |  2020-01-04
```

Desired Output:

```
name   |    date
user1  |    2020-01-01
user3  |    2020-01-03
```

`user1` and `user3` is selected beause they have different addresses within the same day.

`user1` for having different ip addresses at `2020-01-01`.

`user3` for having different ip addresses at`2020-01-03`.

Comment: Please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use group by name and dt

then check the condition by using count(distinct ip address), if it is more than one then pick the record

```
SELECT name, dt
FROM src
GROUP BY name, dt
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) > 1;
```

result

```
name    dt
user1   2020-01-01
user3   2020-01-03
```

Comment: It works. I did not know we can use DISTINCT inside COUNT. Thanks!